# Find the limit of the sequence: $x_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan^{\frac{1}{n}}t \;dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> For $n \ge 2$, define the sequence $\{x_n\}$ by $$x_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan^{\frac{1}{n}}t \;dt$$
> Then the sequence $\{x_n\}$  converges to ________.

My attempt:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan^{\frac{1}{n}}t \;dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\lim_{n \to \infty}\tan^{\frac{1}{n}}t \;dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}dt=0.25$$

But, taking the limit inside the integral is not always allowed (one should show that the convergence is uniform on the finite interval). How do I justify 2nd equality sign in the solution. Can someone please help? It seems to me that my solution is fine, but the justification is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: perform the change of integration variable $s=\tan t$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

In the first quadrant,

$$x\le\tan x\le\frac1{\frac\pi2-x}$$
and
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}x^{1/n}dx\le\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{1/n}x\,dx\le\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{(\frac\pi2-x)^{1/n}}dx.$$

The two bracketing integrals are easy.